# Binding an .AAR in Xamarin Android name does not exist

Tags: android, dll, binding, xamarin, aar

I'm trying to add [this](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager) library to Xamarin project.

I'm following [Xamarin guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/) and going through [binding an .AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) steps. Now I'm stack on step [accessing types](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/#accessing_types).

I added binding library to project references and can see that

```
NamespaceMapping (Java = "com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.library", Managed = "Com.Antonyt.Infiniteviewpager.Library")]
```

but when I use

```
using Com.Antonyt.Infiniteviewpager.Library;
```

in one of my activities it still not recognise the name.

Binding Library Build Action is **LibraryProjectZip**.

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

BuildAction for aar is LibraryProjectZip and this is OK.
Does your project compile? I assume yes, because you have not mentioned any errors.
Sometimes warnings might put some light on why some types are missing (java generics, obfuscated types etc).

Without more info it will be difficult to help you.

Few questions to start:

1. Is api.xml generated? Are your types you need there?
2. Which version of java do you have? Avoid 1.8. Use 1.7.